# How can I add my iCloud email account in Windows Live Mail?

Tags: email, icloud, windows

I have an iCloud account: name@me.com and I try to add it in Windows Live Mail but it gives an error message that my username or password are incorrect.

I found this http://www.apple.com/mobileme/setup/pc/windowsmail.html, but it's online for Windows Vista, my OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recomended way to sync iCloud email is through Outlook, as per [Apple's iCloud PC setup guide](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html)

However as you are asking about Windows Mail I'm assuming you do not have Outlook. In this case you have the option to forward iCloud emails to your other email address (the one you used to setup iCloud perhaps) and route this into Windows Mail.

You should also check that all the fields are correct. Use the [iCloud Mail server](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864) information for this.

Comment: The information in the second link to "iCloud Mail Server" helped me a lot thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I was hesitant to accept this was not possible, but it's just not supported and doesn't work.

---

I too had the same issues on my PC using W7 + WLM2011: not able to send iCloud mail from WLM2011. Following the instructions for Vista + Live Mail doesn't get things working. When using the iCloud Mail server information on the page mentioned above gave me no succes either.

*Error info:
530 5.7.0 No AUTH command has been given. 0x800CCC78*

After a chat with Apple support, the following solution was resolved:

Apple support told me WLM2011 is not supported. Neither is Thunderbird. So much for IMAP and iCloud mail. In practice, it simply is not supported.

Comment: However, it (email) works for me with Thunderbird on Win 7. The only problem that I got: make TB use the built-in Trash folder for deleted messages.

Answer (score 0):

hi Check this post http://santoshsingh.net/?p=482 use the same server setting for your mail client it works perfectly. Also, the new version of Thunderbird automatically configures iCloud so try that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, santosh! Thanks for your answer! While this may answer the question, [it is best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize the contents of the link and provide the link for reference. Links have a tendency disappear over time, leaving a non-applicable answer for those who may stumble upon your answer in the future.